# Jquery ellipsis plugin not working with angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins, ellipsis

I am trying to use [jquery-ellipsis](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/jquery-ellipsis) plugin within ng-repeat using a directive.

```
.directive('ellipsisItem', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).ellipsis();
    }
};
});
```

and my dom is:

```
<li class="list-group-item  ng-scope" ng-repeat="question in questions" ellipsis-item>
{{question.QuestionText}}</li>
```

but i get a list with the content of 
    {{question.QuestionText}}

if i remove the $(element).ellipsis(); it works fine!!

anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap $(element).ellipsis() in $timeout(function(){});

Comment: Please explain why this should work, this would be improve this answer.